# Reset child component data property value from parent component in reactive way in vue js

Tags: vue.js

Parent Component

```
methods: {
   onSubmit() {....}
}
```

Child Component

```
<input v-model="filter" />

data(){
  return {
    filter: ''
  }
}
```

I need to reset the child component input field by resetting the filter property when calling the onSubmit function from parent. Please somebody help to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: move `filter` from **data property** to **props**.

Comment: @Sphinx thanks for your comments. There are multiple child are there and all of them have there own input. All children are creating dynamically. So a common filter is not possible.